# How to avoid scala's case class default toString function being overridden?

Tags: scala, case-class

Scala case class has a default toString function. But when this case class extends a trait with an existing toString() function, it will be rendered useless. How can I prevent this situation?

Comment: There is a similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998866/scala-prevent-mixing-methods

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK here is the easist answer:

```
override def toString = ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
```

end of story:)

Comment: That is DRY and easy.

Comment: noob question: That gave me errors for several reasons; I got this to work:

    `override def toString() = ScalaRunTime._toString(this)`

(I had to add parens after `toString`).  Moreover, I had to have my particular class explicitly `extend Product`.  Any way to avoid this?

(Also, I used `import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime` to avoid fully qualifying the name.)

Comment: @not-just-yeti declaring as case class is equivalent to extend Product. Other parts are related to scala shortcuts in different versions and not important.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a workaround I think may work, it may be too much ceremony, you decide.  It involves a `trait`.

```
trait StandardToString { this:Product =>
  override def toString = productPrefix + productIterator.mkString("(", ",", ")")
}
```

Now trying it with some samples:

```
trait Human {
   override def toString() = "Human"
}

case class European(firstName:String) extends Human
```

and running it with the trait:

```
scala> new European("Falco") with StandardToString
res0: European with StandardToString = European(Falco)
```

of course with the `trait` you are left with

```
scala> new European("Adele")
res1: European = Human
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more precise to say that the case class `toString` is not generated, rather than that it is overridden.

This isn't much of an answer or workaround.

```
scala> trait X { override def toString = "X" }
defined trait X

scala> case class Y(i: Int) extends X
defined class Y

scala> Y(42)
res0: Y = X

scala> case class Y(i: Int)
defined class Y

scala> class Z(x: Int) extends Y(x) with X { override def toString = super[Y].toString }
defined class Z

scala> new Z(42)
res1: Z = Y(42)
```

You can't do that with a trait:

```
scala> trait R extends Y { override def toString = super[Y].toString }
<console>:9: error: Implementation restriction: traits may not select fields or methods from super[C] where C is a class
       trait R extends Y { override def toString = super[Y].toString }
                                                   ^
```