# Whats the best way to restore the default implementation of a case class toString

Tags: scala

Say I do the following:

```
trait A {
    val i: Int
    override def toString = s"A($i)"
}

case class B(i: Int, j: Int) extends A

println(B(2, 3))
```

This will give me the output:

> A(2)

Is there a way I can make B.toString revert to the default toString for a case class without me having to explicitly write:

```
override def toString = s"B($i,$j)"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465951/how-to-avoid-scalas-case-class-default-tostring-function-being-overridden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be

```
override def toString = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
```

but that object <s>was removed in 2.12</s> EDIT: it was only removed from ScalaDoc, but still exists.

To avoid relying on `ScalaRunTime._toString`, you can define it yourself:

```
def _toString(x: Product): String =
  x.productIterator.mkString(x.productPrefix + "(", ",", ")")
```

Comment: Thanks! It just can't be found in Scaladoc for some reason https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/index.html?search=scalaruntime

Comment: The reason it's not in the ScalaDoc is explained in the code: `The object ScalaRunTime provides support methods required by the scala runtime.  All these methods should be considered outside the API and subject to change or removal without notice.`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
trait A {
  val i: Int
  override def toString = this match {
    case p: Product => scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(p)
    case _ => s"A($i)"
  }
}

case class B(i: Int, j: Int) extends A

class Foo extends A {
  override val i = 42
}

B(2, 3)
new Foo
```

which outputs

```
res0: B = B(2,3)
res1: Foo = A(42)
```