# Scala How can Trait override toString Case Class that is Derived Off

Tags: scala, overriding, traits, tostring, case-class

My background is in C++/C and I am trying to learn scala. I am struggling to understand how a trait's toString method overrides case class derived from the trait. Surely the default case class's toString method should over ride the trait's? I am missing something obvious?

Code

```
trait Computer {
  def ram: String
  def hdd: String
  def cpu: String

  override def toString = "RAM= " + ram + ", HDD=" + hdd + ", CPU=" + cpu

}

private case class PC(ram: String, hdd: String, cpu: String) extends Computer 

private case class Server(ram: String, hdd: String, cpu: String) extends Computer

object ComputerFactory {
  def apply(compType: String, ram: String, hdd: String, cpu: String) = compType.toUpperCase match {
    case "PC" => PC(ram, hdd, cpu)
    case "SERVER" => Server(ram, hdd, cpu)
  }
}
val pc = ComputerFactory("pc", "2 GB", "500 GB", "2.4 GHz");
val server = ComputerFactory("server", "16 GB", "1 TB", "2.9 GHz");

println("Factory PC Config::" + pc);
println("Factory Server Config::" + server);
```

Comment: To go with Mario's answer, possibly checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465951/how-to-avoid-scalas-case-class-default-tostring-function-being-overridden)

Comment: It may be worth to mention that in general, a **trait** shouldn't provide `toString` unless you are completely sure you want that for every subtype _(and thus I would make it `final`)_. - Also, many people would argue that you shouldn't really in `toString` at all for nothing but quick debugging, create your own method if you need to turn an object into an Strting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SLS](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) is clear on this point

> Every case class implicitly overrides some method definitions of class
>   `scala.AnyRef` **unless** a definition of the same method is already given
>   in the case class itself or a **concrete definition of the same method
>   is given in some base class of the case class** different from `AnyRef`.
>   In particular:
>
> Method `toString: String` returns a string representation which contains
>   the name of the class and its elements.

Hece because `trait Computer` provides concrete definition of `toString` and is a base class of `PC` and `Server`, then `Computer.toString` is used.